# Como alinhar a exibição de imagens respeitando a altura individual de cada uma?

Tags: css

A exibição das minhas imagens ficam irregular. Veja na abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que ela sejam exibidas de forma alinhada. Fiz uma montagem abaixo para exemplificar o como gostaria que fossem exibidas, pois sei que uma imagem terá altura maior que a outra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CSS:**

```
figure.mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

figure.mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos img{
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px #FF8922 solid;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<figure class="mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos">
    <img src="./adm-gc/fotos/<?php echo $gc_detalhes_fotos['foto']; ?>" alt="Guia Comercial - Guarapari">
</figure>
```

Comment: Amigo tem plugin para fazer isso... deixa eu achar aqui

Comment: As imagens são carregadas de forma dinâmica ?

Comment: @Bsalvo Sim. Ela são carregadas dinamicamente.

Comment: Se existem duas colunas, você pode criar uma div para cada duas imagens que forem carregadas dinamicamente e seu  problema será resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso a estrutura `<html>` tem de ser modificada, é necessário criar duas colunas, e eu aconselho que use `<div>` para a divisão das colunas. Segue o codigo:

**HTML:**

```
    <!--COLUNA-1-->
    <div class="coluna">
        <!--EXEMPLO IMAGENS GERADAS PELO LOOP-->
        <figure class="mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos">
            <img src="example1.png">
        </figure>
        <figure class="mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos">
            <img src="example2.png">
        </figure>
        <figure class="mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos">
            <img src="example3.png">
        </figure>
    </div>

    <!--COLUNA-2-->
    <div class="coluna">
        <!--EXEMPLO IMAGENS GERADAS PELO LOOP-->
        <figure class="mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos ">
            <img src="example4.png">
        </figure>
        <figure class="mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos ">
            <img src="example5.png">
        </figure>
        <figure class="mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos ">
            <img src="example6.png">
        </figure>
    </div>
```

No `CSS` a mudança que fiz foi basicamente dar `width: 50%` na coluna e a `<img>` pegar `100%` desta largura:

**CSS:**

```
.coluna{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos img{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px #FF8922 solid;
}

/* RESET OPCIONAL NO FIGURE */
figure{
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0;
}

/*IMPORTANTE APENAS PARA O EXEMPLO, IGNORAR O ESTILO ABAIXO*/
.coluna:nth-child(1) .mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos:nth-child(1) img{
    height: 100px;
}

.coluna:nth-child(1) .mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos:nth-child(2) img{
    height: 200px;
}

.coluna:nth-child(1) .mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos:nth-child(3) img{
    height: 200px;
}

.coluna:nth-child(2) .mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos:nth-child(1) img{
    height: 300px;
}

.coluna:nth-child(2) .mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos:nth-child(2) img{
    height: 50px;
}

.coluna:nth-child(2) .mais_detalhes_guia_comercial_fotos:nth-child(3) img{
    height: 150px;
}
```